# Why it's impossible to include class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, module

Why "Class < Module" in Ruby, but I can't include class into other class? What is the technical difference between class and module except that the class can be inherited from another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is exactly the difference between Classes and Modules in Ruby - Modules can be included and Classes cannot.  It is simply the design of the language.

Classes are intended to provide concrete functionality open for extension and [Modules provide namespaces and mixin capabilities](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html).  The reason for this difference is probably related to the idea of mixins as replacement for multiple inheritance and interfaces.

Comment: This still begs the question - why can you inherit from a class, but not include it as a mixin?

Comment: If that were possible, class-specific methods such as `self.new` and `initialize` would also be mixed into the class you are using include/extend within. I suppose that if include/extend were to *ignore* these class-specific methods, it could be possible... Challenge Accepted!